# Connecting to apt-cacher server

Tags: networking, 18.04, apt, server, apt-cacher

There is an apt cacher server in my network which i should get connected to , I have configured my proxy setting , but when I try to connect I get this error :

```
Err:1 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic InRelease
  Invalid response from proxy: HTTP/1.1 403 SSL CONNECT proxying not configured  Connection: close  Date: Wed, 18 Mar 2020 09:11:14 GMT  Server: apt-cacher/1.7.11  Content-Length: 0     [IP: 10.x.x.x 3142]
Err:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
  Connection failed [IP: x.x.x.x 3142]
Err:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease
  Connection failed [IP: 10.x.x.x 3142]
Err:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease
  Connection failed [IP: 10.x.x.x 3142]
Err:5 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-proposed InRelease
  Connection failed [IP: x.x.x.x 3142]
Err:6 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease
  Connection failed [IP: x.x.x.x 3142]
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic/InRelease  Connection failed [IP: 10.x.x.x 3142]
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-security/InRelease  Connection failed [IP: 10.x.x.x 3142]
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-updates/InRelease  Connection failed [IP: 10.x.x.x 3142]
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-proposed/InRelease  Connection failed [IP: 10.x.x.x 3142]
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-backports/InRelease  Connection failed [IP: 10.x.x.x 3142]
W: Failed to fetch https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/dists/bionic/InRelease  Invalid response from proxy: HTTP/1.1 403 SSL CONNECT proxying not configured  Connection: close  Date: Wed, 18 Mar 2020 09:11:14 GMT  Server: apt-cacher/1.7.11  Content-Length: 0     [IP: 10.x.x.x 3142]
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

As in the first line you see , it seems that I can connect to the cacher repo server, but why this error is happening ?

Comment: You have to change the ```us.archive.ubuntu.com```s in your ```/etc/apt/sources.list``` file with the IP address of the **apt-cache** server . Then run ```apt update```.

Comment: Thanks Parsa , The problem resolved before by adding ir and us packages in the apt-cache